# Use a mask to find equal columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, mask

I am trying to create a new DataFrame made of the rows in an original DataFrame where the values in two columns are equal and of the same data type. 
I tried using a mask like this,

```
newdf = df[df.column1 == df.column7]
```

However, when I do this, newdf has the same number of columns as df and zero rows. A visual inspection of df shows there are plenty of rows where column1 and column7 are equal.

Any guess as why this is giving me no results and how to improve my mask?

Sample data

Column1     Column7
1/1/2012    4/1/2012
1/1/2012    4/1/2012
2/1/2012    4/1/2012
2/1/2012    4/1/2012
3/1/2012    4/1/2012
3/1/2012    4/1/2012
4/1/2012    4/1/2012
4/1/2012    4/1/2012

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `df.column1.dtype == df.column7.dtype` ?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I ran the print(df.dypes) as my first bit of troubleshooting. I can verify they are the same dtype.

Comment: @nostradukemas is that float ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben no, it is datetime64[ns]

Comment: Would you like show us some sample data ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben added some samples to OP

Comment: It works as expected (newdf = last 2 rows of df) when I test on your dummy string data and convert the columns with `pd.to_datetime`.